# Get SKView size inside custom class in iOS

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

Im trying to make a game with Sprite Kit on iOS. I have a UIViewController with an SKView, and I am using one SKScene.

Now in my scene, I am initializing a 'Player' class, which is just a custom class I wrote, it's a subclass of NSObject. The problem is that I need to know what the screen size is inside my custom class. From what I can tell, the only way to know the screen size inside my custom class is to pass it in from the scene in the Player's initializer.

Is there a more elegant way to do this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply derive the player class from SKNode. You can then add it to the scene hierarchy and then you have a reference to the scene.

You can still have a "model" class containing player data and methods stored inside the custom player node class.

From a MVC perspective and "player" being the model it should in fact not need to know about the screen size because that's a view property. Maybe you simply have this backwards and you actually want to do something on the view side with the information in the player class?

Comment: What I'm trying to do is have the player orbit around the center point of the screen with defined orbits. As the player taps the right side of the screen, the player transitions from one orbit (maybe 50 px in radius) to the next orbit (100 px in radius). As you said, maybe I should reconsider my structure though, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could just use `[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds` within your Player class.  Check out the `applicationFrame` and `scale` properties of a `UIScreen` as well.

You might argue that having a `Player` know the screen size isn't elegant in the first place, but nonetheless this is a way to do it without passing the information into a `Player`.

Comment: Yes that works, and I will take into consideration what you said, thank you!